# xDB Data Migration Tool 3.0.0

Tags: xdb, migration

**First question:**
Do the packages get installed on the Sitecore 8 instance or the Sitecore 9.2 instance?

**Second question:**
The installation guide refers to three files:

1. Data Exchange Framework 3.0
2. xDB Data Migration Tool for Data Exchange Framework 3.0
3. The verification database dacpac file

However the downloads page only has #2 and #3.  Also, the #2 file is corrupt.

Answer (score 0):

The Xdb Migration tool needs to be installled on Sitecore 9.2 instance.

Data Exchange Framework can be download here: https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Data_Exchange_Framework/3x/Data_Exchange_Framework_300.aspx

XDB Migration tool can be downloaded here: https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_xDB_Data_Migration_Tool/3x/xDB_Data_Migration_Tool_300.aspx

Verification database can be downloaded here: https://dev.sitecore.net/~/media/0D0862333B6242399F8814DD169619A3.ashx

Comment: Thanks, but the zip file for the xDB Migration Tool appears to be corrupted.

Comment: Also, it looks like there is a new version of the Data Exchange Framework (3.0.1) here:  https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Data_Exchange_Framework/3x/Data_Exchange_Framework_301.aspx

Comment: I used few month ago 3.0.1  and it works fine.

Comment: When you download the xDB Migration Tool and unzip it, then try to unzip the package within that, do you get an error?

Comment: nope I don't get any error. Please try to install the package into sitecore using Installation Wizard

Comment: Okay, I found the issue. Turns out you can't use Windows to unzip, must use 7zip.  https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/5/t/8812